# How to stream video from multiple camera using AWS kinesis video stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-video-streams, aws-iot-greengrass, amazon-kinesis

I'm using Gstreamer for streaming video to AWS kinesis video stream, I was able to stream video from webcam, but my question how can we stream with multiple camera for computer vision applicatios?

should we use any other plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for Gstreamer for AWS Kinesis already. You just have to setup 2 of them and you're done. Reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/examples-gstreamer-plugin.html